# Viewpager error when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am using viewpager to show around 20 fragments however in some devices I get this error whenever I call notifydatasetchanged() for the PagerAdapter

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler   android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.d()' on a null object reference
ba.b (SourceFile:1634)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (SourceFile:679)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate (SourceFile:166)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.b (SourceFile:1098)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$c.onChanged (SourceFile:3117)
android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged (SourceFile:284)
co.sajan.vaarthakal.MainActivity.c (SourceFile:573)
co.sajan.vaarthakal.MainActivity.b (SourceFile:90)
co.sajan.vaarthakal.MainActivity$5.onDataChange (SourceFile:350)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run ()
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:152)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5507)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: myNews.clear();
        NewsData tempSet = new NewsData();
        tempSet.setItem_type(100);
        myNews.add(tempSet);
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            newsAdapter = new NewsPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), myNews);
            pager.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        } else {
            if (newsAdapter != null) {
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        pager.setCurrentItem(0);